# Apache oozie sharedlib is showing a blank list

Tags: apache, hadoop, oozie

Relatively new to Apache OOZIE and did an installation on Ubuntu 14.04, Hadoop 2.6.0, JDK 1.8. I was able to install oozie and the web console is visible at the 11000 port of my server.
Now while i copied the examples bundled with oozie and tried to run them i am running into an error which says no sharedlib exists.

Installed the sharedlib as below-
bin/oozie-setup.sh sharelib create -fs hdfs://localhost:54310

(my namenode is running on localhost 54310 and JT on localhost 54311)

hadoop fs -ls /user/hduser/share/lib is showing shared library created as per the oozie-site.xml file. However when i check the shared library using the command -
oozie admin -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -shareliblist the list is blank and also jobs are failing for the same reason.

Any clues on how should i approach this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: I have answered a similar question. Just follow this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28702100/apache-oozie-failed-loading-sharelib/31193378#31193378

Answer (score 4):

The sharelib create command looks fine.

If you havent done so already copy the `core-site.xml` from your hadoop installation folder into `$OOZIE_HOME/conf/hadoop-conf/`.
There might already be a "placeholder" `core-site.xml` in the hadoop-conf folder, delete or rename that one. Oozie doesnt get its hadoop configuration directly from your hadoop install (like hive for example) but from the `core-site.xml` you place in that `hadoop-conf` folder.

Comment: Ok, no luck with this. I copied the content of the core-site from my hadoop installation on to the oozie/conf/hadoop-conf/core-site.xml but still the same.

Comment: Any suggestions what could be the possible reason. if any data needs to be pasted here, please do let me know....

Comment: Not sure - how this helped...but i got passed the issue.

Comment: Yes, this helped me too!

Answer (score 0):

Okay i got a solution for this.
So when i was trying to create the sharedlib directory it was doing on HDFS but while running the job local path was being refereed. So i extracted the oozie-sharedlib tar.gz file in my local /user/hduser/share/lib directory and its working now.
But did not get the reason so its still an open question.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue and it turned out that
oozie was not able to communicate with hdfs, as it was not able to find the location for core-site.xml or any other hadoop configuration which has to be declared inside oozie-site.xml. 
Corresponding property in oozie-site.xml is **oozie.service.HadoopAccessorService.hadoop.configurations** 
this property was defined wrongly in my case.
changed it to point to where my Hadoop configuration xmls are present and then it started communicating with hdfs and hence was able to locate the sharelib on hdfs