# Oozie job not working

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I've been trying to run an Oozie job since last few days but its not running. The gets submitted but remain stuck in the "running" state in the Oozie Web console. I'm using using Oozie 4.1.0 and Hadoop 2.6 for this configuration.

I checked Oozie logs and they seem to give the following error :-

```
org.apache.oozie.service.ServiceException: E0104: Could not fully initialize service [org.apache.oozie.service.ShareLibService], Not able to cache sharelib. An Admin needs to install the sharelib with oozie-setup.sh and issue the 'oozie admin' CLI command to update the sharelib  at
org.apache.oozie.service.ShareLibService.init(ShareLibService.java:123)
    at
org.apache.oozie.service.Services.setServiceInternal(Services.java:383)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.Services.setService(Services.java:369)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.Services.loadServices(Services.java:302)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.Services.init(Services.java:210)    at
org.apache.oozie.servlet.ServicesLoader.contextInitialized(ServicesLoader.java:45)
    at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4210)
    at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4709)
    at
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
```

Comment: Did you read the error? `An Admin needs to install the sharelib`

Comment: yes I did. I have already installed the sharelibs using the following command :-
./bin/oozie-setup.sh sharelib create fs -hdfs://localhost:9000

And that seem to have worked fine. I mean I can see the sharelibs being created in my HDFS at the user location.

Comment: Please add additional information such as commands to your question using the edit link. Comments are not for code. I only asked because you didn't include that information in the question

Comment: It also says to do `issue the 'oozie admin' CLI command`

Comment: yes. I did that too. To be specific :

./bin/oozie admin -shareliblist -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie

./bin/oozie admin -sharelibupdate -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie

The first command gives [Available ShareLib] and nothing after that in return.

The second command returns null.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache Oozie failed loading ShareLib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28702100/apache-oozie-failed-loading-sharelib)

Comment: I did that too, making that change on my oozie-site.xml and restarted oozie server but again the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

set property in oozie-site.xml,and restart oozie server:

```
<property>
 <name>oozie.service.WorkflowAppService.system.libpath</name>
 <value>/user/oozie</value>
</property>
```

and dir **"/user/oozie"** is a hdfs dir.

Comment: Do I need to create an oozie user for this purpose ? I created one but it says "User: root is not allowed to impersonate oozie"

Comment: "/user/oozie" is just a hdfs dir, you can also set it to "/tmp/xxx/"

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the property `oozie.system.libpath=true` in your `job.properties` file.